# I'm having issues making changes to my theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I have an issue where I want my theme to not do certain things.

1. I want my theme so stop using a sticky menu.
2. I want a specific page to not display a header.
3. I want h2 linked text to not be grey.

The heading changes i've tried through theme options so far apply to all pages instead of just the one i need.

I've dug into the code with file manager on cPanel but have found so many potentials for variables to change due to lack of expertise.

[This is what i need help changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUVn.jpg)
PLEASE HELP!

Below is what i believe controls my whole main menu. What do i need to alter to make it no longer sticky site wide?

```html
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.main-navigation {
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
 box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: -999em;
 z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
 left: -999em;
 top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
 width: 200px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {

}

.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a,
.main-navigation ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul a.focus {
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
 left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
 left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a {
}
```

Below is what i believe controls the h2 coloring if it is also a url. I do not know for sure though, thats why im here. If i do block specific h2 HTML color it fails to override the theme.

```html
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="range"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="color"],
textarea {
 color: #666;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 3px;
}
```

I Dont know what to look for for the page headers.

Comment: You have to give us some more information about your project so we can help you. Screenshots, code?

Comment: Okay sorry, screenshots incoming.

Comment: just remove all the above uploaded code create a fiddle and upload  full on it and share the link

Comment: The inputs have nothing to do with the H2 style.

what you are looking for is H2 a{}

Answer (score 0):

**I want my theme so stop using a sticky menu.**

Usually this is a built in option on most downloaded themes.
Check Appearance -> Customize
If not use your browser inspect to find the class in your header with the position: fixed; and overwrite it in CSS with !important.

**I want a specific page to not display a header.**

Use your browser inspect to find the page ID calls and then target the header with display:none;.
.page-1 .header{display:none;}

**I want h2 linked text to not be grey.**

h2{color:red;} if you want to override all H2 colours.
To just target the H2 is a certian div use your browser inspect to find the parent classes.

Comment: How do i get the changes i make during inspect to save? I've managed to remove the header on the inspect setting but it won't save the edit.

Comment: You need to save that in your stylesheet.

Comment: Okay so i thought on it awhile.

I managed to remove the header from the new home page by actually publishing is and making it my new homepage instead of a draft. I guess the theme has it stated somewhere that the header is to be omitted on the home page specifically. Though this isn't a FIX it certainly takes care of that issue as it stands.

I'm having much trouble with the Sticky Menu. How exactly do i remove such functionality. What does the code usually look like for this?